# CCID RDR_to_PC_DataBlock Error Problem 0xFE ICC_MUTE - Java Smart Card Reading

Tags: java, android, smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader

I am a beginner programmer and have problem about sending CCID Command to the Smart Card via Usb Host on Android mobile device. This time I sent PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn CCID command PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn to activate the card and received ATR response back.

Next process I sent PC_to_RDR_XfrBlock CCID command to the card for select Applet but I got error response instead.

**CCID Response: 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 FE 00 - 0xFE Meaning CCID Timeout While Talking to ICC**  about error code is Reference in Document DWG Device Smart Card Integrated Circuit Device (s) Section 6.2.6.

I find information to slove this problem but not found way to resolve. How I can resolve this issue and get APDU response back to 90 00?

More information

```
#1 This Byte array is the ATR value (answer to reset) that I get from RDR_to_PC_DataBlock answer is
ATR response: 3B 68 00 00 54 48 20 4E 49 44 20 36
Reference ATR value at https://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/
```

```
#2 This Byte array is APDU command that I combine with PC_to_RDR_XfrBlock CCID command to select Applet.
6F 0D000000 00 01 00 0000 00A4040008A000000054480001

Applet used to select Thailand Personal DF name of the APDU command line from this link.
https://github.com/chakphanu/ThaiNationalIDCard/blob/master/APDU.md
```

For response I am not good at English but I will try to sent information as I can if you want, Thankyou for your help.

---

Normally I use 2 these command

1 PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn

```
Command (byte) 0x62, (byte) 0x00000000, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x0000
```

1 RDR_to_PC_DataBlock

```
Response 80  0C  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  3B  68  00  00  54  48  20  4E  49  44  20  36
```

---

2 PC_to_RDR_XfrBlock (with APDU Selet Applet)

```
Command (byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0x0000000c, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x0000, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xa4, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0xa0, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0x48, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01
```

2 RDR_to_PC_DataBlock

```
Response 80  00  00  00  00  00  00  40  FE  00
```

reference for this link
[Communicate with smartcard reader through Android USB host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40975868/communicate-with-smartcard-reader-through-android-usb-host)

Comment: Could you please post the complete CCID trace with all command and reponse messages.

Comment: Hi, You can see all CCID command from this pdf link: https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/DWG_Smart-Card_CCID_Rev110.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I am very familiar with the specification. I want YOUR trace of command and response messages, including PowerOn/PowerOff/GetSlotStatus etc...

Comment: Mr.Paul please see in below answer, Thank you

Comment: please do not use the answer functionality for additional info but edit your question instead

Comment: my suggestions is that you check the response data of a getSlotStatus command. Additionally you should find out why the second data block has a sequence number of 0, as it should have 1 like in the XfrBlock

Comment: what reader are you using and have you tried switching to another reader?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? i have your exact same problem