# How to construct correct PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn when communicating with CCID HID reader

Tags: android, usb, smartcard, hid, smartcard-reader

**What I am doing:** I am trying to create an Android application that can connect to an HID reader, read an HID smart card, and authenticate the user who has scanned their smart card.

So far, I am able to detect that a USB device has been connected (via [`UsbManager`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40996141/8023531)), ask for permissions to communicate with the USB device, and detect when permission has been granted to communicate with the USB device.

When I detect that permissions have been granted, I use [`UsbDeviceConnection`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40996141/8023531) to send a `PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn` command to the correct [`UsbEndpoint`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40996141/8023531). I am then receiving back an ATF through a `RDR_to_PC_DataBlock` response.

This is the `PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn` I am sending to the reader: `62 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

This is the `RDR_to_PC_DataBlock` response I am receiving: `80 00 00 00 00 00 00 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`.

**What my problem is:** Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40996141/8023531), and through referring to the [CCID documentation](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/DWG_Smart-Card_CCID_Rev110.pdf), I've determined that the `42` in the response is "status register" and that there is no error coming back from the response. Still, this status register value should be `00` on success, which it isn't. I am also not getting back any data, so something is definitely off.

**What I've tried so far:** I've tried incrementing the `bPowerSelect` field in the `PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn` to 1, 2, and 3 (via passing `62 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00`, etc.) and am getting back the same `RDR_to_PC_DataBlock` every time. I've also tried incrementing the slot number (via passing `62 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00`, etc.) and am receiving an error (`80 00 00 00 00 01 00 42 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`). Finally, I've tried incrementing the sequence number for the `PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn` to 1, 2, and 3 (via passing `62 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00`, etc.) and am getting the same `RDR_to_PC_DataBlock` response, but with an incremented sequence number (`80 00 00 00 00 00 01 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`).

I've tried passing the above strings (beginning with `80 00 ...`) into the following [ATR Parser](https://smartcard-atr.apdu.fr/) but am getting [a bad response](https://smartcard-atr.apdu.fr/parse?ATR=80%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2042%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000%2000) each time and cannot make much sense of it.

**What I'm wondering:** How can I go about figuring out the correct way to format my `PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn` based on the `RDR_to_PC_DataBlock` responses I am getting back? I know that the `42` in the "status register" field of the response is a clue, but am unsure how to use this information to construct my `PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn` command correctly.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? i'm trying to read a smart card content too. i'm stuck on the bulkTransfer method. I never receive any response.

Comment: @GabbrIssimo no :( but I am also a flutter Dev :)

Comment: Please let me know if you figure this out, and I will let you know as well if I figure it out.